# Give all grid elements width of widest element but keep from stretching

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

I have this grid which, because of the text, has one div that is slightly wider than the rest. How can I make the first ones the same size as the last without moving or stretching anything ?

Can this be achieved with CSS or do I have to use Javascript ?

(EDIT I reproduced a simple example)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  width: fit-content;
}

li {
  width: fit-content;
  background: coral;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Name</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Name</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>A larger name</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your html and css on so we can have a look please?

Comment: I added the code with a simple example but it is the same principle. I want the width of the two first divs to grow to the size of the last one.